# php PDO fetchAll with foreach not working

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdo, foreach

I'm having some problems with PDO selecting from Database in order to generate dynamic Sitemap file based on articles (essentially pages). PHP is not throwing any errors as I don't see any errors in the error log. Here is the code.

**SELECT STATEMENT SNIPPET**

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY aid ASC");
$r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**FOR EACH SNIPPET + XML**

```
foreach($r as $row) {

$format_date = date('Y-m-d', $row['date']);
$format_slug = strtolower($row['slug']);

echo '
<url>
    <loc>'.$format_slug.'</loc>
    <lastmod>'.$format_date.'</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
';

}
```

**XML DATA BEFORE "FOREACH"**

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
      <loc></loc>
      <lastmod>2017-01-27</lastmod>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
      <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
      <loc>contact-us</loc>
      <lastmod>2017-01-27</lastmod>
      <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
</url>
';
```

**XML DATA AFTER "FOREACH"**

```
echo '</urlset>';
```

And I am using proper PHP header for the XML output at the very top of the page which is

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

So ones I navigate to the Sitemap url, the predefined data in the echo statements is returned, in this case the 2 data snippets in the *BEFORE "FOREACH"* part and of course the *AFTER "FOREACH"* is returned.

However for some odd reason no data is being fetched from the database even truth the script seems to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to execute the statement.

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY aid ASC");
$q->execute();
$r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Alternatively you can use PDO::query http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php.

Comment: thank you, kind of odd that i forgot that, haven't had enough sleep i guess lol.

Answer (score 1):

Have you forgotten to call `Execute` on `statement`?